# .NET Core console application crashes on debug

Tags: c#, console-application, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

2-3 days ago I have updated all Nuget packages and checked - everything worked.

Then I upgraded from `System.Data.SqlClient` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and configured what needed for the connection to work - everything worked.

Then I upgraded from .NET Core 7 to .NET 8 and everything worked.

Today, I'm trying to debug the code for a problem, and it crashes with the error:

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core. The program '[42000] console.exe' has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

In the console window, I get this:

> (process 42000) exited with code -1073741819.

I have tried everything I have found here on stack and on Microsoft community.

Restarted VS, Restarted computer, reinstalled .NET 8 SDK, reinstalled VS, even tried to open need solution with no code in it beside "HELLO WORLD"

But nothing is working.

Please advice

Update #1 - `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Properties\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Properties\**" />
    <None Remove="Properties\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appSettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appSettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus" Version="4.5.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.44.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="MailTemplates\File.html">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Update2 - the cause
Eset anti virus is to blame. Their deep inspection module stoped all cmd functionality in the computer

Comment: Weird that "Ensure that the target..." seems to want to run into "...process is configured to use .NET Core."  Together they form a coherent known error message.  I suspect a formatting error in your question.  I'll edit to repair.

Comment: I would suggest a cleanup of the output folder of the project. When there is some "old" stuff dangling around weird things might happen.

Comment: what do you mean by formatting error? the new console app have only WriteLine("HELLO WORLD"); and it crashes

Comment: Literally in the question itself there was a markdown problem with the quoted error message.  (I made an edit)

Comment: @Ralf I even opened new solution from scratch. same error

Comment: @Y.G.J Please share your `.csproj` file, verbatim.

Comment: Csproj I will add to the question. What is the verbatim you need to see?

Comment: @Dai you can see the csproj file in the question

Comment: @Y.G.J Unrelated-tip: you don't need the `<Scc...>SAK` MSBuild properties at all - they've been obsolete for at least a decade now.

Comment: what do you mean? it was probebly was added by AzureDevOps (TFS)

Comment: To check if the cause is Visual Studio, or an install thing with .NET, you could try (outside VS), in an empty directory: `dotnet new console` followed by `dotnet run`. when this produced "`Hello, World!`" you know that the cause of your problem might be Visual Studio related, and not .NET (8) related.

Comment: so you were right, it worked, got the hello world. but it is not VS problem... my command line is crashing all the time, dllhost.dll is crashing - something weird is going on

Comment: You may consider checking to see if your hard drive/SSD is failing. Before proceeding, ensure that you've backed up any important files.

Comment: " got the hello world." (which is from the command line) AND "my command line is crashing all the time".  These 2 two commands (both command line) state the opposite reaction on a command line. **Your question does need more info ...**

Comment: Please read: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), because it should **not** be done by using [edit] on the question ....

Answer (score 1):

First time post and possibly not related.

We had issues since 9PM yesterday (07/03/24) with Exchange IIS and .NET
Same Exception code.

Turns out to be our Trellix ATP being the cause, still troubleshooting now.
If you have ATP might be worth disabling it to test.

Update: Simply running update now in Trellix ENS resolved our issue and ATP is now enabled again. No more access violation errors for .NET